# Adding html code in radio label

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am fighting with customize on symfony forms for twig...

My problem is to add html inside a label for a radio button like `<strong>25</strong>` but it is escaped by default and I can't find how to unescape. I use the following code.

```
{% block choice_widget %}
    {%
    set labels = {
        1: { title: '1 ' ~ 'label.credits'|trans ~ ' - <strong>1€</strong>' },
        2: { title: '2 ' ~ 'label.credits'|trans ~ ' - <strong>2€</strong>' },
        25: { title: '25 ' ~ 'label.credits'|trans ~ ' - <strong>25€</strong>' },
        }
    %}

    <div {{ block('widget_container_attributes') }}>
        {% for child in form %}
            {% if child.vars.value matches '/^[1|2|25]{1}/' %}
                {% set currentLabel = labels[child.vars.value].title %}
            {% else %}
                {% set currentLabel = '' %}
            {% endif %}
            {{ form_widget(child, {'label': currentLabel}) }}
            {{ form_label(child) }}
            {{ form_errors(child) }}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: did you find out eventually? Thanks :)

Comment: No I didn't find

Comment: I've just solved a similar issue on how to do this for a checkbox, just posted an answer on how you could solve it for your problem - if you still have it / need it! hope this helps ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you will need to override the `form_label` block and incorporate into your own theme (https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_customization.html), this is for bootstrap 4 (find the file in vendors folder called `bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig`, if you need this for bootstrap 3 just do the same but the file is `bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig`), notice where I've inserted the `<strong>` and `</strong>` tags:

```
{% block form_label -%}
    {% if label is not same as(false) -%}
        {%- if compound is defined and compound -%}
            {%- set element = 'legend' -%}
            {%- set label_attr = label_attr|merge({class: (label_attr.class|default('') ~ ' col-form-label')|trim}) -%}
        {%- else -%}
            {%- set label_attr = label_attr|merge({for: id}) -%}
        {%- endif -%}
        {% if required -%}
            {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({class: (label_attr.class|default('') ~ ' required')|trim}) %}
        {%- endif -%}
        {% if label is empty -%}
            {%- if label_format is not empty -%}
                {% set label = label_format|replace({
                    '%name%': name,
                    '%id%': id,
                }) %}
            {%- else -%}
                {% set label = name|humanize %}
            {%- endif -%}
        {%- endif -%}
        <{{ element|default('label') }}{% if label_attr %}{% with { attr: label_attr } %}{{ block('attributes') }}{% endwith %}{% endif %}><strong>{{ translation_domain is same as(false) ? label : label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}</strong>{% block form_label_errors %}{{- form_errors(form) -}}{% endblock form_label_errors %}</{{ element|default('label') }}>
    {%- else -%}
        {%- if errors|length > 0 -%}
        <div id="{{ id }}_errors" class="mb-2">
            {{- form_errors(form) -}}
        </div>
        {%- endif -%}
    {%- endif -%}
{%- endblock form_label %}
```

You can try the above by putting it in the actual twig view and putting this statement above it:

```
{% form_theme form _self %}
```

Extra (for a checbkox): To achieve this for a checkbox you will need to override the label template, pull out the block for 
`{% block checkbox_radio_label -%}` from `bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig` or `bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig` and then incorporate this into your own theme.

Extra extra (for a checkbox): If you also need to customise the widget, pull out the block for `{% block checkbox_widget -%}` i.e. remove the label rendering from within it (yes, for some internal reason the widget generates the label as well) and customise the way you want it to be. This way even calling `form_label` on a checkbox will output the label (otherwise `form_label` will not output anything)

Comment: How do you differentiate between a "row"-label and a "widget"-label? I need the labels of my actual radio buttons to have different html then the label for my row of radio buttons...

Answer (score 1):

Look here : http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#select-tag-checkboxes-or-radio-buttons

You can put the parameter `expanded` to true and `multiple` to false in your formType for have radio buttons in your html

Comment: Yes thanks, but my question is to add html inside the label, not to add radio buttons, this I know how ;-)